# How to customize the Google Docs URL?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I want access docs.google.com using docs.mycompanydomain.com, how can I do that? Notice that at https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#CompanyProfile:flyout=customUrl appear a lot of URLs to customize, but not Docs. My Google Docs settings have few options, and no allow customization of URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to set new custom URL mapping for Google Docs editors.

## Explanation

Google Docs editors URL format change was announced at the beginning of 2015. If the Google Apps administrator set the URL mapping before the change were rolled out to the organization it should continue to work but if he didn't he can't create a custom URL mapping for Google Docs editors:

- http://docs.google.com
- http://sheets.google.com
- http://slides.google.com
- http://drawings.google.com
- http://script.google.com

## Alternative

None that I know about.

## References

[Google Docs editors URL format change - Google Apps update alerts](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/02/google-docs-editors-url-format-change.html)

Answer (score 2):

**For Clarification**

You cannot change your "docs" using the Admin Panel; that only works for **mail, drive, calendar, groups and sites**.  You can add any of these by making a CName entry and pointing it to ghs.googlehosted.com as explained by Ruben (above).

In order to change anything else, you must manually make the DNS entry point to the actual URL you are interested in:

- docs.mydomain.com: **CName = "docs.google.com"**
- sheets.mydomain.com: **CName = "sheets.google.com"**

I've found that in general it's just simpler to use "mail.mydomain.com" and use THAT as your entry to all of the other Apps.

Answer (score -3):

You need to create a new CNAME record pointing to Google . Then go to Simple DNS Zone Editor. Select the domain name you would like to setup with Google Docs from the “Select a Domain” drop-down menu. In the “Add an CNAME Record” section enter docs in the “Name” text box and enter ghs.google.com in the “CNAME” text box. Click the Add a CNAME record button. Now at Google Docs, you need to change the Google Docs URL in Google Apps so that you can access it through your domain.

Comment: What I'm asking is how do "Now at Google Docs, you need to change the Google Docs URL in Google Apps so that you can access it through your domain." I know the procedure that you describe, but just don't know where set the custom URL at google docs settings. BTW, is not ghs.google.com, is ghs.googlehosted.com.